# Flexible way to return the cell range of a table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list, formatting

I am looking for the correct property in VBA. I want to assign a list in one sheet using table data in another sheet. I want to avoid using the direct cell numbers, and would like the object to return the correct range of cells regardless of how long the table is. My code is throwing an application-defined/object-defined error at the .Add Type line.

If Not (.Range("J10").Value = "") Then

```
        Range("I10").Select
        With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=Worksheets("data").ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange

            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution to create a list that updates with the table using VBA.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""Table6[test data]"")"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```